# YouTube ClientLogin alternative special use case / upload to multiple user accounts

Tags: upload, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I'm stuck on this issue for days, hopefully someone out there can help me out..

Here is my use case:
Different users to my app can provide their username/password to YouTube so that they can use my app to upload videos to their YouTube accounts. I used ClientLogin and it had been working fine, but it is deprecated now and I can't find an alternative. I tried oauth2 with service account but it's not similar since there are multiple users on my site.

One of my thoughts is to have them log in once with their username/password and save the access code and refresh code, then refresh it every time my app makes a request to google/youtube api. But I can't get it to work since it was getting complicated with errors.

```
Google::APIClient.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'YouTube Hook',
  :application_version => '1.0.0')

key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :authorization_uri => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
  :issuer => service_account_email,
  :signing_key => key)

client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

Is there any example out there that I can learn from to apply to my case?

Answer (score 0):

Not understandable what you want to achieve.

If it's just you want people to upload into their account. OAuth2 will do that. (Service accounts are not supported in YouTube APIs anyway.)

If you want users to upload in your account, then there is [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/) for that.